# custom boolean converter to set style class

Tags: jsf, converters

A Converter is defined in faces-config.xml which changes a boolean into a String "Yes" or "No"

```
<converter>
    <converter-id>booleanConverter</converter-id>
    <converter-class>com.example.BooleanConverter</converter-class>
</converter>
```

This works fine using

```
<h:outputText value="#{bean.booleanValue}" converter="booleanConverter" />
```

But if the intention was to style a surrounding `div` element is this possible using a converter?  For example if a Converter was defined which return String "booleanTrue" and "booleanFalse" (which are defined in CSS)

```
<converter>
    <converter-id>booleanStyleConverter</converter-id>
    <converter-class>com.example.BooleanStyleConverter</converter-class>
</converter>
```

Could I do something like:

```
<div class="#{booleanStyleConverter.getAsString(null,null,bean.booleanValue)}">
    <h:outputText value="#{bean.booleanValue}" converter="booleanConverter" />
</div>
```

Defining in backing bean works but seems unsatisfactory

```
public String booleanStyle(boolean value) {
    BooleanStyleConverter bsc = new BooleanStyleConverter();
    return bsc.getAsString(null, null, value);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of the converter is to change the value that's saved to the backing bean into something desirable. Why are you not just using `class="#{bean.booleanValue}"`?

Or even simpler still : `class="textBox.value eq 'true'? 'booleanTrue': 'booleanFalse'"`, where `textBox` is the binding of the textbox:

```
<div class="#{textBox.value eq 'true'? 'booleanTrue': 'booleanFalse'}">
    <h:outputText binding="#{textBox}" id="textBox" value="#{bean.booleanValue}"/> 
</div>
```

Comment: 1) Comparing a boolean to a boolean in string format in a boolean expression makes little sense. Just check the boolean itself directly. In other words, get rid of `eq 'true'`. 2) You're confusing `id` with `binding`.

Comment: Truth @BalusC. For #1, the textbox won't recognize it as a boolean, if it's being typed in. Are you saying the String will be converted automatically to a boolean?

Comment: It's bound to a `boolean` property. So it's boolean already. Even then, if it were a `String` with value `true`, EL will do the coercion magic.

Comment: Didn't see a value binding from the backing bean to confirm a type, but that's good to know about EL @BalusC